# Magento and Angular.JS

Tags: theme, javascript, frontend

I was wondering if someone had a set of best practices or an example of a template that uses Angular.js with Magento.

I am working on a template with javascript functions and I wanted to use Angular.js, do you have any recommendations and is it recommended to use this framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Vinai Kopp did a presentation about using Angular with Magento during Meet Magento (DE, ES). His presentation can be found here: http://netzarbeiter.com/media/mm14es/magento-and-angularjs/#/. Maybe this is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I found the [video of the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcq9vOgS-Ao) (the first 10 seconds are in german but you can add the subtitles). I was hoping a more practical example or a tutorial.

Comment: @Aphroz Could you please explain how did you do this as the video is unavailable